# Find all i18n tags in project and generate yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, locale, rails-i18n

I recently started a project that has a REALLY messed up locales file.
I guess about 50% of the 10.000+ lines are locales from landingpages they're not using anymore.

Is there a way to go over all the views and find the i18n strings

```
 t('profile.button1')
```

They're about to hire translators to translate their locale files but if I give them the file like this they will be stuck translating 5000 lines that will never be used anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a quick & dirty program hope help you (me too)

```
v1 = ARGV[0]
 file = File.open("keys.txt", "w")
 File.open(v1) do |f|
   f.each_line do |line|
     if line.include? "I18n"
       file.write(line[/I18n.t \((?:\'|\")(.*?)(?:\'|\")/m, 1])
     end
   end
 end
```

call it whit the file you want to parse as argument and it should extract all I18n keys in a file called keys.txt. Maybe you should adapt to your program, but I tested on my erb files and works